# Statistical test for count data passing a given threshold

Tags: count-data, threshold

Apologies if this question is painfully basic. I have a df of count data in which each row represents a box of marbles, some of which are black, and some are white:

```
Box_number   Total_marbles    Number_White    Percent_White
001          6                4               0.4
002          8                0               0.0
003          5                1               0.2
004          12               0               0.0
...
```

I'm interested in the proportional representation of white marbles among the **whole** sample. Before collecting the data I predicted that at least 20% of the marbles would be white. Obviously I can test this by examining the absolute count data (total number of white / total number of marbles). My question is this - is there a more sensible way of testing my hypothesis, as opposed to merely reporting a descriptive statistic?

Thanks!

Comment: Statistical significance would be useful if you did not have access to the whole sample. If there were 100 boxes, and you had 20, then you might do a hypothesis test and determine if the actual proportion for those 20 boxes was significantly different from your hypothesis that it is 20% for the entire population.

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett let's say that's the case. What kind of test would you recommend? I've considered running regression on my percent_white variable, but it's extremely zero-inflated. I'm trying to avoid zero-inflated models because they split the data into +ve values versus zeros, whereas I really want to analyse the whole sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were only counting a sample from a population, and you want to test if the population mean is 20%, then you would use a one-sample t test. Your null hypothesis is that the mean is 20%-- do the results of counting your sample boxes disprove this hypothesis (at a certain confidence level)?

[A good example of how to do this in excel](http://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/one-sample-t-test/). You need to re-shape your data so that instead of being summarized by box there is one row per marble. For your example, you could make a list of 31 numbers, where the first 5 are 1's and the last 26 are 0's. You don't need to count and record them one by one, the order will not matter.

In that excel example cell `e9`, the alpha, is the confidence level. You may want to change that. You need to change `e8` to .2 (or whatever hypothesis you want to use).